# Social Plugins: Is it possible to use any in a Java EE 6 environment?

Tags: social-networking, java-ee-6, spring-social, seam3

As we know we have some social plugins for Java EE, like Spring Social and Seam Social.

The problem is that I m not using spring neither seam.. I'm using a Java EE 6 app using netbeans, with a javaee-web-api-6.0.jar to WAR project and EJB3.1 to EJB.

Well, my question is, do you guys know how to use sprint social or seam social in this case?

Or better, do you know any other API to social, like these two, but to work in a environment without spring or seam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the tech lead of Seam Social.

Seam 3 is not strictly a framework (like was Seam 2) but a collection of CDI extensions and CDI beans library. It is targeted to all CDI implementation. So you use those libs to extends your toolbox without leaving Java EE and CDI.

Being part of it Seam Social can be used with any environnement that has CDI (a Java EE 6 container would be the best solution).

Beside Spring Social (which will be very hard to use in your environment) and Seam Social, there are not generalist social network solution. You'll have to get specific libs for each social network (Twitter4j for Twitter is a good solution)

Comment: Good to know.. this week I will make some tests with Seam Social and until the weekend I will be back with more news. Thanks for answering.